# How do I change this theme's menu behavior back to 12.04's behavior?

Tags: themes, menu

Using a Radiance derived theme in 12.04 the menu item pointed to by the mouse or selected by cycling through using the keyboard was always had a single color background and a contrasting text color (in my case, the item pointed to was white text on a blue background while other items are black text on a gray background.

After upgrading to 12.10 the unselected items are as usual but the pointed to item now has white text on a pale gray background rectangle on top of the blue background.  I'm guessing that one definition in the gtkrc file has been added or split into two, but I can't immediately see which one it is.

There is a similar effect in the places bar in applications, e.g. in gedit's file open dialog box and nautilus' places bar above the window displaying the content of the folder (you can guess I don't know the correct terms for these particular features).

I'd like to have the same behaviour as I had with 12.04. Which definition needs modifying or is there a new one I need to add?

Comment: I can't really make out a _question_ here. Could you please clarify where exactly you need help?

Comment: I'd like to have the same behaviour as I had with 12.04.  Which definition needs modifying or is there a new one I need to add?

Comment: GTK 3 themes *need* to be updated. You'll have to wait. Also GTK 3 themes make no use of gtkrc. Moreover themes for Gnome 3.6 need to be compiled into a binary.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that it's the gtk.css and settings.ini files in gtk-3.0 that I modified.  It's been six months and I forgot where I had made the changes. Any ideas what needs to be changed to get my old behaviour back?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same. The reason is that after upgrade you have different versions of mac-os-x themes mixed up.

If you don't want to mess with /usr/share/themes directory then

- go to Synaptic Package Manager,
- search for 'mac-os' packages
- remove noobslab 'precise' ppa
- add 'quantal' ppa's for mac-os-x-theme

Worked form me right away but try to logout / login just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Uri is partially correct.  The GTK3 themes Radiance/Ambiance have been thoroughly revamped, but after an upgrade old variants will still be in the /usr/share/themes and ~/.themes folders.  I deleted all of those and created a blue-grey version of Radiance based on the new Radiance theme.  You don't need to compile them into a binary.

A couple of observations for anyone who wants to make their own variant.

1. Images in the assets folder are a mix of RGB and indexed files.
2. There are a few hard coded color choices in the css files you may need to change to go along with your revised images in the assets folder.